# How to pass slug to UpdateView?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to get a slug field to be passed accessing an `UpdateView` but when I click the button it does not redirect or do anything for that matter.

I am used to using a `<int:pk>` while handling `UpdateView`s but in this scenario I am using an open source app which uses a slug field for it's URL.

**URL:**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update/$',
    view=QuizUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='quiz_update'),
```

**Model attribute and method:**

```
url = models.SlugField(
    max_length=60,
    blank=False
    )

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('quiz_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'slug': self.url})
```

**Template:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="location.href='{% url 'quiz_update' slug=quiz.url %}">Update Test</button>
```

**View:**

```
class QuizUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Display a form for updating a quiz

    **Context**

    ``quiz``
        An instance of :model:`quiz.Quiz`

    **Template:**

    :template:`quiz/<slug>/update/`
    """

    model = Quiz
    fields = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'receiver',
        'url',
        'category',
        'max_questions',
        'random_order',
        'answers_at_end',
        'exam_paper',
        'single_attempt',
        'pass_mark',
        'success_text',
        'fail_text',
        'draft',
    ]
    success_message = 'Quiz successfully updated!'

    def test_func(self):
        quiz = self.get_object()
        print(self.request.user.employee_type)
        print(quiz.receiver)
        if self.request.user.employee_type in quiz.receiver:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: can we look at your `quiz_update` view code

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

similar to your get absolute url method you can define get update url as below and call it in your templates

```
def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse('quiz_update', kwargs={'slug': self.url})
```

Comment: How should I be pointing to this? As it doesn't seem to be a [method inherited](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) by `UpdateView`s. I just realized that neither does `get_absolute_url`.

Comment: you can use it as {% for quiz in object_list %}{{ quiz.get_update_url }} {% endfor %}

Comment: I am not trying to filter my `ListView`, I am trying to update the object with a form similar to a `CreateView`.

Comment: check your quiz keyword (slug=quiz.url) works in template

Comment: Yes, it does. `/quiz/test1/update/` was displayed in the template.

Comment: it should show the slug also after /update/. Check, whether it is working without javascript first, also if you post your full template, it will be helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202241/discussion-between-david-alford-and-user6837382).